# Datetimepicker Linked Base on Dropdown

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have form with publish and unpublish date

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Publish Date : <em>*</em></label>
    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker-publish" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss">
        <input name="publish_at" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Unpublish Date : </label>
    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker-unpublish" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss">
        <input name="unpublish_at" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

According to [documentation](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers), it's simply to make linked date

```
$('#datetimepicker-publish').datetimepicker({
    sideBySide: true,
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
}).on('dp.change', function(e) {
    $('#datetimepicker-unpublish').data('DateTimePicker').minDate(e.date);
});

$('#datetimepicker-unpublish').datetimepicker({
    sideBySide: true,
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    useCurrent: false
}).on('dp.change', function(e) {
    $('#datetimepicker-publish').data('DateTimePicker').maxDate(e.date);
});
```

I have no problem up here. But i need when i change some dropdown, `minDate` and `maxDate` has change too in publish and unpublish date form

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Category : <em>*</em></label>
    <select id="select-picker" class="form-control input-sm show-tick" title="Select Category" name="category" required>
        <option data-min-date="2017-01-01 00:00:00" data-max-date="2017-04-01 00:00:00" value="1">- Cat ABC</option>
        <option data-min-date="2017-04-01 00:00:00" data-max-date="2017-07-01 00:00:00" value="2">- Cat DEF</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I set default data with using `data-*`

```
$('#select-picker').change(function() {
    var min_date = moment($(this).find(':selected').data('min-date'));
    var max_date = moment($(this).find(':selected').data('max-date'));

    $('#datetimepicker-publish').data('DateTimePicker').minDate(min_date.toDate()).maxDate(max_date.toDate());
    $('#datetimepicker-unpublish').data('DateTimePicker').minDate(min_date.toDate()).maxDate(max_date.toDate());
});
```

My test case :

- choose ABC (2017-01-01 00:00:00 - 2017-04-01 00:00:00) then choose DEF (2017-01-01 00:00:00 - 2017-04-01 00:00:00) = OK
- choose DEF (2017-01-01 00:00:00 - 2017-04-01 00:00:00) then choose
  ABC (2017-01-01 00:00:00 - 2017-04-01 00:00:00) = Publish date cannot
  back to 2017-01-01
- choose ABC (2017-01-01 00:00:00 - 2017-04-01 00:00:00) set some data
  then choose DEF (2017-01-01 00:00:00 - 2017-04-01 00:00:00) =
  TypeError: minDate() date parameter is after options.maxDate:
  2017-04-01 00:00:00
- choose DEF (2017-01-01 00:00:00 - 2017-04-01 00:00:00) set some data
  then choose ABC (2017-01-01 00:00:00 - 2017-04-01 00:00:00) = Publish
  date and unpublish date cannot reset

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ytrpb308/